# PHP url decode do not work

Tags: php, urldecode

I have an URL in which parameter pass is urlencoded:

```
http://ipaddress/userandpass.php?user=test&pass=145Red#321OK
```

In order to decode this param I have tried to use `urldecode and rawurldecode and utf8_decode(urldecode())` but without succes.
My code looks like this:

```
if(isset($_GET["pass"]) && $_GET["pass"] != ""){
$pass=urldecode($_GET["pass"]);
}
```

Do you have any ideas about how could I solve this issue ?

Comment: What's issue you are facing?

Comment: I am trying to decode pass parameter: 145Red#321OK should be only Red#321. Can I do this with urldecode()?

Comment: have you read manual for urldecode()?

Comment: check this http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Comment: you simply want to remove 145 from parameter, right ?

Comment: no no, i want to decode this parameter. Pass parameter can have any encoded value. I simply want to decode this value. For example if I have value Gyr@1234 for pass, it will be encoded in whatever value and I want after decode to obtain the initial value, which in this case will be Gyr@1234. It seems that this do not work for a value which contain # and which was encoded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use

```
if(!empty($_GET["pass"]))
{
    $pass= $_GET["pass"];
}
```

[PHP - GET & POST Methods](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_get_post.htm)

```
http://www.test.com/index.htm?name1=value1&name2=value2
```

- The GET method produces a long string that appears in your server logs, in the browser's Location: box.
- The GET method is restricted to send upto 1024 characters only.
- Never use GET method if you have password or other sensitive information to be sent to the server.
- GET can't be used to send binary data, like images or word documents, to the server
- The data sent by GET method can be accessed using `QUERY_STRING` environment variable.
- The PHP provides `$_GET` associative array to access all the sent information using GET method.

Comment: If $_GET['pass'] is "0", checking using !empty will fail

Comment: @kafsoksilo its never happen. Check it

Comment: <?php

$x = '0';

if(!empty($x))
{
  die("NOT EMPTY");
}

Comment: you should use `if( isset($_GET["pass"]) && !empty($_GET["pass"]))` event if you solution works 99% of the time it's still not the best solution

Comment: I made some tests and it seems that $_GET["pass"] do all the work. I didnt knew that. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quiet sure that you are tying to do but I assume your password can have all sorts of characters in it, including the ones usually found as key element in a query string.

Although you should consider to never sent parameters that contain sensitive data in the GET or uri in the first place anyway.

But to answer your question:
I would do it this way :

```
$parts = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
array_shift($parts); //we dont want the first bit, only everything after the first questionmark
$qstring = implode('?', $parts);
parse_str($qstring, $parameters);
if (isset($parameters["pass"]) && $parameters["pass"] != "") {
    $pass = urldecode($parameters["pass"]);
}
```